# Kill execution of a blazorserver page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am writing a blazorserver application. This application contains an authentication form with Microsoft Identity.

I have wrote a helper which tells if user should see the page or not:

```
@page "/pageurl/"
@if (true) { MyHelper.CheckUserPermission() }
....
```

And here is a part of my App.razor file:

```
  <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
      Message i want to see if user permissions are not good
    </NotAuthorized>
  </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

I have tried to put a NavigationManager.NavigateTo in CheckUserPermission function, when user permissions are not good. But the page execution is done anyway.

My question is: what should i put in my CheckUserPermission function for stoping page execution, and display the NotAuthorized message ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use roles instead. And use @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin, superuser")]
on the page on which you want to prevent access.

If you must use the logic you presented, then create a service that checks the user access level:

```
public class AuthChecker
{
    public bool HasAccess(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
       /// logic

    }
}
```

And then on the razor page:

```
@inject AuthChecker checker

@if(checker.HasAccess(user))
{
  // component if authorized
}else
{
  // component if not authorized
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't use roles because i have a very specific logic to implement.  I have tried your HasAccess method, but i don't want to have a big if. What I want to do is to check if (!checker.HasAccess(user) { return/break/die } Thanks

Comment: Ok. Then put it Navigation event in OnInitialized/OnParametersSet? Also, do you want the user to see only access denied or do you want to log him out?

Comment: In fact it does not matter if user see message or if he his log out. What i want is to put the check line at the top of the file (not in OnInitialized) and i want to be sure no code will be executed or show to the user if he doesn't have access. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have never done that before so I can't comment. But you might want to write a custom AuthenticationStateProvider and see if you can place that logic there.

Comment: I have also tried to create a custom AuthenticationStateProvider but i cannot put my logic in this file: I have a lot of different logics on my different pages...

Comment: With all due respect, your Authorization logic should be simple-- is this user authorized to view this page?  If you are using more than that, you probably shouldn't be.